# Error: Cutline feature without a geometry. > Raster Type

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, masking

I've got an `Error: Cutline feature without a geometry` on QGIS 2.4.0 Chugiak.
I have 2 samples (A raster type and a vector type), they have the same coordinates (EPSG:4253 - Luzon 1911) Then I tried using Clip on my Raster type,
Raster > Extraction > Clipper

Then I masked my vector to my raster, and got that error, Any Help would do. Or if you want I could send you my files.

Comment: I tried the validation thing, but there were no errors found. Can you think of any other reason this error would appear?

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem right now (QGIS 2.6.1). But shapefile has some issues (topologic issues). I guess that shapefile has to be repaired before being used as crop mask.

Topological issues in shapefiles can be repaired using GRASS GIS. Here's a really simple guide of how to repair a bad polygon. You only need to know how to use GRASS GIS.

https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/bad-bad-polygon-fixing-invalid-geometries-with-quantum-gis/

This guide help me resolve my problem with a polygon shapefile with topological errors. Then, cropping was as easy as usual using QGIS tool and gdal warp tool.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen is the vector shape file used for masking contains more than one polygon. So check the attribute table of the vector mask and delete the unnecessary polygons.

Comment: I had a second Polygon without geometry. After deleting it, the algorithm works succesfull.

Answer (score 0):

Check attribute table of the shapefile, in all likelihood there is no field in it for area, use $area to put in area of current feature/polygon.

Comment: The area can't be computed if there is no (or it's broken) geometry.

Answer (score 0):

If you negatively buffer a shapefile of polygons, then some polygons may loose area completely and thus have no geometry. These need to be removed before the gdal operation will run.